# Find user name(who updated) and last updated time of a unix file in two diffrent variable?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have file `file1.txt` to which I want to know who and when it got updated in two different variables. Also time of creation in other variable. I tried the commands below to no purpose

```
find /unix_work -mtime -1 -ls
find /unix_work -type f -mmin -2
grep -H /unix_work/file1.txt /home/*/.bash_history
stat file1.txt
```

Comment: Are you working on bash port of Windows? If so, please add the info to question.

Comment: It seems you want 3 things: 1. username who last updated, 2. time of last update, 3. time of creation. Right? BTW the first one is not possible. You could get the name of the owner of the file, but not who updated it.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @janos, you can also not get the creation time of the file.

Comment: @janos If he is on a linux machine, `audit deamon` logs might be of help. Provided the op has an audit configuration in place just the `ausearch` would help give both the user who accessed the file along with the access timestamp.

Comment: @sjsam looking at the file paths in the attempts, it doesn't look like in Linux

Comment: @janos Indeed, that is why I asked the op to mention in question if he is on a bash port  for windows.. Waiting for the question to get updated. See he has mentioned `unix file` in the title..

Comment: It is unix file.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
birth_stat_file1=`stat file1.txt --format="%W"`
birth_stat_file2=`stat file2.txt --format="%W"`
FROM_EMAIL=xyz@gmail.com
To_EMAIL=xyz@gmail.com

while true
do

    last_change_stat_file1=`stat file1.txt --format="%Z"`  
    user_name_file1=`stat file1.txt --format="%U"`

    last_change_stat_file2=`stat file2.txt --format="%Z"`  
    user_name_file2=`stat file2.txt --format="%U"`

    if (( $last_change_stat_file1 > $birth_stat_file1 )); then
        echo "mail from here !!!!!!!!!!"
        echo "$user_name_file1 file has changed at $last_change_stat_file1..." | mailx -r $FROM_EMAIL -s "File1.txt has changed" $To_EMAIL
    fi

    if (( $last_change_stat_file2 > $birth_stat_file2 )); then
        echo "mail from here !!!!!!!!!!"
        echo "$user_name_file2 file has changed at $last_change_stat_file2..." | mailx -r $FROM_EMAIL -s "File2.txt has changed" $To_EMAIL
    fi

    birth_stat_file1=$last_change_stat_file1
    birth_stat_file2=$last_change_stat_file2

    sleep 30  #change time in seconds to fix hits

    echo "hit [CTRL+C] to stop this loop!"

done
```